# Best way to update CollectionView content after jQuery UI Sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, ember.js

I've been able to get jQuery UI Sortable working in Ember.js thanks to @ghemton's `safeClone` method: [Ember.js + jQuery UI Draggable Clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797632/ember-js-jquery-ui-draggable-clone)

I'm having trouble letting Ember know of the change though once the sort has completed. Right now, I'm using `splice` as suggested in [Move an array element from one array position to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another) to move the item in the collection to its proper place. That works fine but I'm having an issue with window scrolling.

In this jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/chrisconley/g4aE6/, if you scroll to the bottom, then reorder any of the elements, the window jumps back to the top. If you put a breakpoint in between `propertyWillChange` and `propertyDidChange`, you can see that Ember is removing all of the items from the view momentarily, which is causing the window to jump back to the top.

```
App.MySortableView = Em.CollectionView.extend({
  moveItem: function(fromIndex, toIndex){
    var items = this.get('content');
    this.propertyWillChange('content');
    item = items.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0];
    items.splice(toIndex, 0, item);
    this.propertyDidChange('content');
  }
});
```

Is there a way to notify Ember of the change without it removing and replacing the entire collection?

**Updated Solution:**

(Thanks to Christopher Swasey's answer below)

```
App.MySortableView = Em.CollectionView.extend({
  moveItem: function(fromIndex, toIndex){
    var items = this.get('content');
    item = items.objectAt(fromIndex);
    items.removeAt(fromIndex);
    items.insertAt(toIndex, item);
  }
});
```

Full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisconley/NN35P/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using JS standard library calls on objects like Array. These calls aren't trappable by Ember's bindings/observers. Instead, use the APIs defined by Ember, such as 'replace', 'objectAt', etc. to interact with arrays.

In this case, you'll want to swap out #splice with #replace.

Comment: Thanks! That did it - original question has been updated with a solution.