# Using jsPlumb in an Ember.js Application

Tags: ember.js, jsplumb

I am trying to learn how to use [jsPlumb](http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html) in my [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) application so I put a minimal [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/xZVzQ/6/) together to demonstrate how they could work together.

In this example so far I just insert the nodes and add them to jsPlumb. I have not added any links between them yet. At this stage the nodes should be **draggable** but they are not.

Error I get in the browser console:

```
TypeError: myOffset is null
```

Which points to this part of the code in jsPlumb:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var _el = _getElementObject(inputs[i]), id = _getId(_el);
    p.source = _el;
    _updateOffset({ elId : id });
    var e = _newEndpoint(p);
    _addToList(endpointsByElement, id, e);
    var myOffset = offsets[id], myWH = sizes[id];
    var anchorLoc = e.anchor.compute( { xy : [ myOffset.left, myOffset.top ], wh : myWH, element : e });
    e.paint({ anchorLoc : anchorLoc });
    results.push(e);
}
```

You can see that a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/4XwfZ/) without integration with Ember.js works as expected. I know that this version of jsPlumb I have uses jquery-ui to clone elements and support drag and drop. [A post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797632/ember-js-jquery-ui-draggable-clone) shows there is an issue with jquery-ui draggable functionality in Ember. However, I am not sure if I am hitting the same problem. If that is the same issue I am having, I would appreciate some help in how to implement the solution suggested there in my application. I am new to both Ember and jsPlumb, so I would appreciate clear guidance about what is going on here and what path to take.

How can I make this example work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily my suspicion was wrong and the issue was not with metamorph. jsPlumb and Ember work just fine together, without any hacks. I put a little [example in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/xZVzQ/15/) that demonstrates how they could work together.

Credit goes to Simon Porritt who helped me at jsPlumb user group to identify the problem. What I was missing was a simple call to `jsPlumb.draggable element`. However, the above error persisted after this fix.

The particular error message above was result of Ember calling `didInsertElement` an extra time with an element which did not make it to the DOM. I have reported this [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1400). One workaround is to check the element makes it into the DOM before calling jsPlumb. As you can see in the jsFiddle I have added this code in the `didInsertElement` hook to get rid of the error.

```
elementId = this.get 'elementId'
element = $("#"+elementId)
if element.size() > 0
  console.log "added element", element
  jsPlumb.addEndpoint element, endpoint
  jsPlumb.draggable element
else
  console.log "bad element"
```

Hope this helps someone.